# Why does printing the 'address of index n' of c style strings lead to output of substring

Tags: c++, pointers, char, cout, ostream

I'm rather new to C++ and while working with a pointer to a char array (C style string) I was confused by its behavior with the ostream object.

```
const char* items {"sox"};
cout << items << endl;
cout << items[0] << endl;
cout << *items << endl;
cout << &items << endl;
cout << &items[1] << endl;
```

Running this leads to:

```
sox
s
s
0x7fff2e832870
ox
```

In contrary to pointer of other data types, printing the variable doesn't output the address, but the string as a whole. By what I understand, this is due to the `<<` operator being overloaded for *char arrays* to treat them as strings.

What I don't understand is, that `cout << &items[1]` prints the string from index 1 onward (`ox`), instead of the address of the `char` at index 1. Is this also due to `<<` operator being overloaded or what is the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back in the olden days, when C ran the world, there was no `std::string`, and programmers had to make do with arrays of `char` to manage text. When C++ brought enlightenment (and `std::string`), old habits persevered, and arrays of `char` are still used to manage text. Because of this heritage, you'll find **many** places where arrays of `char` act differently from arrays of any other type.

So,

```
const int integers[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
std::cout << integers << '\n';
```

prints the address of the first element in the array.

But,

```
const char text[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' };
std::cout << text << '\n';
```

prints the **text** in the array `text`, up to the final 0: abc

Similarly, if you try to print addresses inside the array, you get different behavior:

```
std::cout << &integers[1] << '\n';
```

prints the address of the second element in th array, but

```
std::cout << &text[1] << '\n';
```

prints the **text** starting at the second character of the array: bc

And, as you suspected, that's because `operator<<` has an overload that takes `const char*` and copies text beginning at the location pointed to by the pointer, and continuing up to the first 0 that it sees. That's how C strings work, and that behavior carries over into C++.

Answer (score 6):

The type of `&items[1]` is `const char *`.  Therefore the `const char *` overload of `operator <<` is used, which prints the string from index 1 onwards.

OTOH, the type of `&items` is `const char **`, for which no specific overload exists, so the address of `items` is printed (via the `const void *` overload).

Comment: Yes, that's what I figured. +1.

Answer (score 0):

`items[1]` is the second character of the array and its address, i.e. `&items[1]`, is a pointer to the second character (with index 1) as well. So, with the same rule that you have mentioned for `operator <<`, the second character of the string till the end is printed.